# Ember group helper and itemController

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to use [ember group helper](https://github.com/emberjs/group-helper) with `each` statement and `itemController` attribute and it isn't working as expected. With group helper I can't read properties from item controller.

Demo with group attributes: http://jsbin.com/jurecogejubo/2/

Demo without group attributes: http://jsbin.com/jurecogejubo/1/

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the group helper: https://github.com/emberjs/group-helper/issues/7